# How can I return a populated deferred object from other module?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to understand the deferred object in JavaScript.  I am also using the [revealing module pattern](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript.), which is working well.

I have the following bootstrapper code:

```
function bootStrapper() {    
    var result = xmlRepository.loadAll();   
}
```

in xmlRepository I have a 'private' function:

```
function loadAllXML() {
    var d = $.Deferred();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost/Autopolicy/dataSource.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            d.resolve(xml);
            $xml = xml;
        }
    });

    return d.promise();
}
```

I then have a 'public' function called loadAll() hat look ssomething like:

```
function loadAll() {
    loadAllXML().done(function (xml) {
        // I want to return the populated xml to the bootstrapper
    });                
}
```

The value returned to the bootstrapper is always undefined.

How can I modify the code so that var result = xmlRepository.loadAll()); has an xml poulated result?

Thanks

Comment: There is a syntax error in your call to loadAll() (an additional closing parenthesis)

Comment: Thanks, yeah, that's not in the actual code :)

Comment: You cannot return anything from asynchronous callbacks. The anonymous function inside .done() will be called asynchronously. So loadAll() will be long finished before this method will be called.

Comment: That';s what the defer, resolve and.promise do.  I have managed to get it working and will post the solution.

Comment: @davy did you manage to get around to that solution?